# How to transcode short video using FFmpeg, libx264 codec, Swift, iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, video, ffmpeg, libx264

The goal is to transcode a short video into .mov format using [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) and libx264 codec.
So far I have not been able to do this using third-party libraries.
Using the command line, the video is perfectly transcoded, but I need it inside the application.

If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful.

The resulting video needs to have the following parameters, something like this:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNQiR.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUHK.png) [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUoXl.png)

For example:

```
let command = ["ffmpeg", "-i", videoOutputURL.path, "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "copy", convertedVideoUrl.path]
let ffmpegCommand = ffmpeg(command)
```